# Upload File Denied by Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I recently implemented a file upload function within my spring mvc application, but unfortunately it doesn't work as it constantly gets blocked by Spring Security. If i disable CSRF in Security Configuration it works, so it leads me to believe something is wrong there.

Spring config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**","/user/secure").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().anonymous()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/error-login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .userDetailsService(userAccessDetails)
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(16000)
    ;
}
```

file upload form:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Single File</h4>
    <form method="POST" th:action="@{/test/uploadFile}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"/><br />
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated guys.

NOTE: I've had to recreate the question as original i deleted by mistake

Comment: Why the down vote? The question is legitimate and meets all the required criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can do three things.

1) Implement Multipart filter as mention in Spring CSRF documentation (See below link for more detail example)
-- http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipartfilter

along with multipart resolver bean
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

--- Pretty much this should work unless there are more customize code involve during upload. if it has some customization then option 2 is better

2) Implement SpringSecurityFilterchain in config. add Multipart filter before security filter start executed. implement multipart resolver.

3) nothing works then try to convert file in Json at client side and post it as a binary data to the server. (its a workaround and try to avoid as its not a good design to do that). -- for example pdf2json you can use this js file

Let me know if any of the option helps.

Comment: 1 and 2 don't work as I've tried that in multiple combinations. The 3rd one is as you said not good design, that i'd rather avoid. The seems like a actual bug with spring security

Comment: If you got any examples of 3 i could use it to see if i can find a proper fix

Comment: I would like to know what issue did you face in 1 and 2 can you give more detail on it? for 3 there are third party plug ins for jquery such as pdf2json,csvparser etc. google it with example you will get lot of sample code in that conversion hook it with your server side call for upload.Mean time I will make one working example for you and give it you.

Comment: Yea i went away from part 3 in the end, going to hack the spring code to make it work. Both 1 and 2 return same result of access denied. for the 2nd one i used beforeSecurityFilter function or whatever its called to create new Multipart filter just in case. That didn't work. I am just going to blatantly hack it and get it to work that way. Kind of suprised spring sec doesn't allow for this basic capability on a simple level.